# cmd syntax error net user password

Tags: syntax, passwords, cmd

I've been a bit stupid and managed to ruin my friend's account up a bit. What happened was:
I was going to change the name of his user from "Firstname Surname" to "Firstname Penis Surname". To do this, I went into the cmd on his laptop as an admin (windows button -> cmd -> ctrl+shift+enter). Then I wrote

net user USER fullname:"Firstname Penis Surname"

What I didn't realize was that I forgot the "/" before "fullname", and so I changed the password of the user, rather than changing the fullname. The problem now is... we can't figure out what the password for the account is. We have tried out practically everything..
fullname, fullname:"Firstname Penis Lastname", fullname:, fullname:"Firstname, Lastname", etc. etc., but nothing works.
So, since the syntax for changing the password for a user through the cmd is

net user USER PASSWORD

and I used ":" and "/" and "(space)" the syntax somehow got messed up, and we can't figure out the password. Needless to say, the old password does not work any more. 
Anyone know what the account password would be when I messed up the syntax like I did?
Cheers

Operating system: Windows 7

Comment: Have you tried with `fullname:Firstname Penis Surname`? I mean without quotes.

Comment: If you are the Administrator of the system then you can change the password of the user. Right click `Computer` `Manage` `Local Users and Groups` `Users` Right Click the user name `Change Password`.

Comment: Spaces are not allowed in Passwords. So try `fullname:"Firstname`. (forget about the rest after the first space)

Answer (score 0):

hmmm...This is may work, depending on your privileges. Assuming you did not log out:

Run Command Prompt as an Administrator, it should let you do this without a password;
Type Net user YOURNAME *

type your password

type your password (Again)

and you should be done -Day